# Как сделать, чтобы всплывающая подсказка не показывалась с помощью css?

Tags: css

Обычно, когда наводится курсор на элемент с атрибутом title, появляется всплывающая подсказка, расположенная в title.

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы подсказка не показывалась с помощью css?

https://jsfiddle.net/cw967207/2/

```css
a[title]{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="test title">test text</a>
```

Comment: что значит: скрыть атрибут?

Comment: атрибут нет, элемент с атрибутом да

Comment: @Grundy, обычно, когда наводится курсор на элемент с атрибутом title, появляется всплывающая подсказка, расположенная в title. Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы подсказка не показывалась с помощью css?

Comment: [Is it possible to hide the title from a link with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15364063/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy pointer-events:none для ссылки? Зачем вообще тогда ссылка?)

Comment: @Cheg, это уже другой вопрос :-)

Comment: нет, нужно чтобы работала ссылка, про это небыло ничего сказано в вопросе. вопрос был в том, как скрыть title

Comment: @word Добавьте в вопрос

Comment: кароче никак это сделать нельзя?

Comment: Если только силами CSS - то никак

Comment: @word, а зачем это может понадобиться, если не нужен title, может проще его сразу из разметки убрать?

Comment: Если title вам нужен лишь для какого-то кастомного тултипа, то можно заменить его на другой аттрибут, например, data-title

Comment: @Grundy, ну как-бы согласитесь, что не добавлять атрибут title не составляет труда при вёрстке. Если бы была проблема в том, чтобы просто не добавить атрибут title, я бы эту проблему давно решил. Задача стоит исправить уже готовый сайт без js!

Comment: @word, глобальный replace делается очень просто

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15364063/2881286

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Такое не предусмотрено в css.

- Если `title` заменяется каким-то скриптом на кастомный тултип, убрать атрибут должен этот скрипт.
- Если `title` просто не нужен, то и не надо его писать.
- Если тег `img`, то следует использовать не `title`, а `alt`.
- Если текст должен заменять иконку, можно подумать о `aria-label`.

Comment: там говорят: pointer-events:none вполне себе запрещает tooltip :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну пость ответом, что уж поделаешь, не догадался :) И поставь ассоциацию между вопросами.

Comment: там только проблема в том, что и нажать-то ее тож нельзя будет :-)